# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows⠀

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. I saw a lot of tutorials and they do partitioning, but I'm confused if I should do partitioning or just select the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows". Will I get the same result if I choose the first option in the installer?

[image]

Comment: Alongside is (or was) a feature of Ubuntu install process.  The feature may have been dropped.  I can't find images of the option in the install steps of version 18.04.  You'd save time by exploring the [steps provided for Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) and asking questions concerning those steps which might not be clear.  You can also "steal" grab images from there to help make your question clear.  If you can't find it there, it might not exist as an install option.  Someone else may be able to comment if they have seen the option in 18.04.

Comment: Dude if you want dualboot, you must free space from windows first; with the disk administrator utility, shrink space and then boot the pendrive. If you freed space, then it is totally safe to use that option

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install Ubuntu on a separate drive. Otherwise, if for any reason, you need to reinstall either OS, other OS files will be erased. For example, if you reinstall Windows, formatting the drive, you can get back ubuntu installation in the previous state. You just have to recover Ubuntu boot.

Answer (score 0):

They should be identical, however you might have more options when it comes to formatting (e.g. encrypting your whole disk, etc.). So it is all up to yourself.